# How do I move a Vector Point from one LonLat to another in OpenLayers? I am using OSM

Tags: vector, position, openlayers, point, openstreetmap

Here is the code I use. What should I code inside the function moveFeature() such that the point will move from one position to another.

```
    <script>
  function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
    var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
    var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
    var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(0,0).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
    var zoom           = 15; 

    map.addLayer(mapnik);
    map.setCenter(position, zoom );
        var style_blue = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
    style_blue.strokeColor = "blue"; 
    style_blue.fillColor = "blue"; 

        var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Simple Geometry");

    // create a point feature
    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(0,0).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
    pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, null, style_blue);

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(point.x, point.y), zoom);
        vectorLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature]);
        window.setInterval(function() {moveFeature(pointFeature)}, 1000);
      }
      function moveFeature(feature){
        var newLonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(1,1).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
        //how do I move the feature to the new LonLat here
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do I move the feature to the new LonLat?
Here is the  answer:

```
feature.move( newLonLat );
```

Comment: Thanks JJones, I was able to do it through:

    feature.geometry.move(newlon - oldlon, newlat - oldlat);